# SQLite query time AM v PM

Tags: database, sqlite, time, datetime-format

I have an SQLite table with 2 columns of time saved as HH:MM:SS format (24 hr clock)... for example, the first entry is 00:00:00 Col1 and 00:00:59 Col2 .... and this continues +1min until the last entry at 23:59:00 Col1 and 23:59:59 Col2....

I currently use a query to see which intervals the current time (time at query) is between and then it returns the corresponding value in Col3 (assigned variables I created)... the code is as follows

```
"SELECT column3 FROM time WHERE column1 <= time('now', 'localtime') and column2 >= time('now', 'localtime') "
```

This code effectively returns the appropriate value in Col3 but **ONLY when the current time is PM** (between 12:00:00 and 23:59:59)...I don't understand why it works for the PM values and not the AM values when the table is in a 24hr format HH:MM:SS.. i struggled with a similar query but with the date and the solution turned out to be a formatting issue in the CVS file before importing to SQLite...so is this a query or format issue?... or both?... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a problem in your formation.. TRY hh:mm:ss

Comment: SOLVED....I didn't properly format in Excel... although it appeared to be in hh:mm:ss it wasn't truly in that format.. I applied a custom format to the suggested hh:mm:ss then it worked... thanks